# CURL GET request to an search form

Tags: php, curl

```
$url3 = "http://cocatalog.loc.gov/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?DB=local&PAGE=First";
$ch3 = curl_init();                   //2nd curl to search ASIN 
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_URL,$url3);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch3, 156, 2500);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_GETFIELDS,"?Search_Arg=$Kindletitle&Search_Code=TALL&CNT=25&HIST=1");
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$copyrightrecordresponse = curl_exec($ch3);
curl_close($ch3);
```

Trying to do an GET request to the following search form but I am getting the error
curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given,

Comment: why you use this **curl_setopt($ch3, 156, 2500);** in your code. I think this is giving error

Comment: @DarkWish CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS has 156.

Comment: then use these **CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS should be 155** and **CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS should be 156** [see here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#107314)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i am missing something but why dont you form the request URL beforehand? Not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish but see if this works for you:

```
$title='teste';

$url3="http://cocatalog.loc.gov/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?Search_Arg=$title&Search_Code=TALL&CNT=25&HIST=1";

$ch3 = curl_init();                   //2nd curl to search ASIN 
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_URL,$url3);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch3, 156, 2500);

curl_setopt($ch3,CURLOPT_HTTPGET,true);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$copy= curl_exec($ch3);
curl_close($ch3);

echo($copy);
```

This returns the search results for the string stored in the $title variable.

See this reference link from the documentation about curl options:

http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Hope it helped. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**First**. There is no CURLOPT_GETFIELDS in [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php) .

**Second**. $Kindletitle may contain URL delimeters. So, avoid things like that:
`"?Search_Arg=$Kindletitle&Search_Code=TALL&CNT=25&HIST=1"`

Use [urlencode](http://www.php.net/urlencode)().
But I'd use an array() and [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)():

```
$data = array(
    'Search_Arg'  => $Kindletitle,
    'Search_Code' => 'TALL',
    'CNT'         => 25,
    'HIST'        => '1'
);    
$query = http_build_query($data);
```

For `GET` use:

```
$url = 'http://example.com?'.$query;
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

Or use `POST`:

```
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query );
```

---

Note about the `curl_setopt($ch3, 156, 2500);` and `156`.
It's equal for `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` for Windows platform. For some reason, `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` is defined incorrectly in some versions of PHP. Probably not your case, use `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` instead of `156` to be clear.